# Probability of two strings being equal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, matrix-equations

Given a matrix $A\in F_2^{n\times m}$, (let $m< n$ and $A$ has full column rank)  what is the probability under the distribution ( $y,y'$ uniformly random in $\{0,1\}^m$), such that $Ay=y'$? I am not sure if it should be $1/2^m$ or $1/2^n$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the set $\mathbb{F}_2$? I'm sure it's common, but I had never heard of it.

Comment: Just wanted to say its a matrix filled with 0-1 entries. SOrry for the confusion

Comment: @molarmass: The notation $\mathbb F_2$ refers to the set $\{0,1\}$ as a field equipped with addition and multiplication; more generally, $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ is the [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) with $p^k$ elements.

Comment: @prob_freak: Your edit has made the question inconsistent; you're now first specifying a distribution for $y'$ but then saying that it's fixed.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a distribution; I'll assume uniform distributions throughout.

$y'$ may or may not be in the image of $A$. If it is, then since $A$ has full column rank, there's exactly one $y\in\mathbb F_2^m$ such that $Ay=y'$, so the probability is $2^{-m}$. If it isn't, then the probability is $0$.

If instead $y'$ is picked randomly, the probability of it being $Ay$ is $2^{-n}$; so this is also the probability for $Ay=y'$ if both $y$ and $y'$ are picked randomly.

Comment: So if i understand right, if both $y,y'$ are picked uniformly at random, then the probability is $1/2^n$. If $y'$ is fixed, the probability is either $1/2^m$ or 0?

Comment: @prob_freak: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $1/2^m$ or $0$, depending on whether $y'$ is in the range of $A$ or not. Try the case $m=1$ to get a feel for this.